# Checking and Installing .net 4.0 before while installing my forms app in SharpSetup WIX

Tags: .net, wix

I don't have a lot (this is my first go of it) of experience with WIX, so I decided to use the SharpSetup template in VS 2012 to get it up and running quickly. Now my problem is that I need to install .net on the users machine for them to use the app, but all the answers I've found on here talk about using a 'chain'. Again I don't know where I'd but this. I assume the .net installer I put in the same folder that I my .exe in but I'm swinging at anything at the moment.  You can see I tried and failed solving this problem by including the .net installer exe in the same group as my project. If someone could explain where in the code I implement this .net check/install I'd greatly appreciate it!

Here's my WIX:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<?include Product.Defines.wxi ?>



<Fragment>
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs">
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="!(loc.APPNAME)">
      <Component Id="pmd" Guid="{9d848b50-cab5-4f96-abe3-4c551c7335db}">
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\$(var.AppCode)\ProgramMenuDir" Type="string" Value="ProgramMenuDir" KeyPath="yes" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuDirRF" On="uninstall" />
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
  <Directory Id="StartupFolder" Name="Startup" />
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="$(var.AppCode)">
      <Component Id="MainExecutable" Guid="{bbd95e2b-9f33-4c67-80d9-9b80f3f52001}">
        <File Id="MainExecutableFile" Name="SampleApp.exe" Source="..\ProductBuild\sampleFile.txt" KeyPath="yes">
          <Shortcut Id="MainExecutableStartMenu" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="!(loc.APPNAME)" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Icon="icon.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes"/>
          <Shortcut Id="MainExecutableDesktop" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="!(loc.APPNAME)" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Icon="icon.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
        </File>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="SubFeatureExecutable" Guid="{0b30137e-621e-49a1-83bb-d0b50c3834b8}">
        <File Id="SubFeatureExecutableFile" Name="SampleLibrary.dll" Source="..\ProductBuild\sampleFile.txt" Vital="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="DocumentationPound" Guid="{006f5e3e-bb68-409c-8c30-37dc82a0a3f9}">
        <File Id="DocumentationPoundFile" Name="Pound.currency" Source="..\ProductBuild\sampleFile.txt" Vital="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="DocumentationEuro" Guid="{a1e06fa0-0293-4314-ad3b-5a82b7cde17e}">
        <File Id="DocumentationEuroFile" Name="Euro.currency" Source="..\ProductBuild\sampleFile.txt" Vital="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="DocumentationCommon" Guid="{578635b1-b912-428e-b161-3507465bced9}">
        <File Id="DocumentationCommonFile" Name="help.exe" Source="..\ProductBuild\sampleFile.txt" Vital="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="DocumentationEnglish" Guid="{434f103e-7be8-49ac-b90b-9675f42e6caa}">
        <File Id="DocumentationEnglishFile" Name="English.documentation" Source="..\ProductBuild\sampleFile.txt" Vital="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="DocumentationFrench" Guid="{bd132536-94c6-488d-aa8a-700d4070718f}">
        <File Id="DocumentationFrenchFile" Name="French.documentation" Source="..\ProductBuild\sampleFile.txt" Vital="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="DocumentationGerman" Guid="{045e065e-bc43-418d-97fc-701b0d80dca3}">
        <File Id="DocumentationGermanFile" Name="German.documentation" Source="..\ProductBuild\sampleFile.txt" Vital="yes" />
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLLOCATION">
  <Component Id="dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" Guid="{c5e5282e-dafe-4e51-857f-2648bbcb743c}">
    <File Id="fil8a9sd8fa9s8df9a8fs98fd9sfa908sdf" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\ProductBuild\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="EntityFramework.dll" Guid="{C8010F46-05CF-4D73-8F69-6F68176EC558}">
    <File Id="fil34ECF92861B5C4F79E50A3EE293AC68A" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\ProductBuild\EntityFramework.dll" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="EntityFramework.xml" Guid="{C68D3DE4-D338-4C83-96F1-DCF7D1FA1AAC}">
    <File Id="fil04EFBF6DC1A33030A49CFCE8889F7E70" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\ProductBuild\EntityFramework.xml" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="PetesTimeTray.exe" Guid="{C1891D2B-9815-42A3-BCD7-3316F0F28AC7}">
    <File Id="fil7AC61C1EB5B94A1F447DA90D87BB454B" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\ProductBuild\PetesTimeTray.exe">
      <Shortcut Id="PetesTimeTrayStartMenu" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="!(loc.APPNAME)" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Icon="icon.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
      <Shortcut Id="PetesTimeTrayDesktop" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="!(loc.APPNAME)" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Icon="icon.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
      <Shortcut Id="PetesTimeTrayStartUp" Directory="StartupFolder" Name="!(loc.APPNAME)" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Icon="icon.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
    </File>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="PetesTimeTray.exe.config" Guid="{321EFADC-29DD-4E41-BED0-5B360FAEBBA0}">
    <File Id="fil1DC527512D4271328F383F45C1F9229B" KeyPath="yes"    Source="..\ProductBuild\PetesTimeTray.exe.config" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
<ComponentGroup Id="PetesTimeTrayFiles">
  <ComponentRef Id="dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" />
  <ComponentRef Id="EntityFramework.dll" />
  <ComponentRef Id="EntityFramework.xml" />
  <ComponentRef Id="PetesTimeTray.exe" />
  <ComponentRef Id="PetesTimeTray.exe.config" />
</ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the .NET framework is installed by linking to the NetFxExtension with light. Just add a `PropertyRef` to the one you want. You can find a list of those properties [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html).

Say you want to make sure .NET framework 4.0 Full is present before installing your software, you'd add this somewhere in your source code:

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL" />
<Condition Message=".NET Framework 4.0 Full is not installed.">
    NETFRAMEWORK40FULL
</Condition>
```

When running the MSI, the `LaunchConditions` action will run and check if the `NETFRAMEWORK40FULL` property is set. If it is, the installation continues, if not, the installation fails.

However, if you wanted to install the .NET Framework beforehand, you'll need two WiX projects. One for your basic MSI, and one for your bundle (this is the chain you heard about). There's a tutorial [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html) on how to do just that.

```
<Bundle>

    ...

    <Chain>
        <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Redist"/>
        <MsiPackage Id="MyApplication" SourceFile="path to your msi"/>
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

You'll have to link against the NetFxExtension here too. The list of possible .NET packages are listed [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html).